# Entity Framework insert many to many record with existing parents

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables: `Video`, `Course`, and `CourseVideo`. I want to do an insert into `CourseVideo`.

The `Video` may or may not have an existing record, but when it does I want to use the existing record and NOT create a new record.

My code looks like this:

```
var video = db.Videos.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Link.Equals(link));

if(video == null)
{
    video = new Video { ... };
    db.Videos.Add(video);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

var course = db.Courses.Include("Videos").Single(c => c.ID == courseID);
course.Videos.Add(video);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This adds a record in the many-to-many table (`CourseVideo`) but it also creates a new record in the `Video` table.

How do I prevent the insert into the `Video` table if it already exists?

Comment: In what scenario does it add the duplicate video: when it already exists or when it doesn't?

Comment: When it already exists

Comment: Looking at the code I don't see why it would insert it twice. Is all of this in one `using(MyContext)` statement or are they retrieved separately? A detached `video` object would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Using a primary key in the Video table? And using 2 pk in the junction table, CourseID and VideoID.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the insert into the Video table if it already exists, the added video must be in the context. You don't need to call savechanges() for the new video.

Answer (score -1):

EF does not check if an entry exists in case of N:M relations by default.

You should put your course changes inside the `if` statements:

```
var video = db.Videos.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Link.Equals(link));

if(video == null)
{
    video = new Video { ... };
    db.Videos.Add(video);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var course = db.Courses.Include("Videos").Single(c => c.ID == courseID);
    course.Videos.Add(video);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```